# Jquery DataTable display all OR 50 Records at once without any pagination in Metronic admin theme

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have configured table in this way under my HTML file

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-full-width" id="sample_2">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th class="hidden-480">BuySell Difference</th>
         <th class="hidden-480">Stock</th>
         <th class="hidden-480">LP</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

I have this thing under table_managed.js file

```
 $('#sample_2').dataTable({
            "aLengthMenu": [
                [5, 15, 20, -1],
                [5, 15, 20, "All"] // change per page values here
            ],
            // set the initial value
            "iDisplayLength": 5,
            "sDom": "<'row-fluid'<'span6'l><'span6'f>r>t<'row-fluid'<'span6'i><'span6'p>>",
            "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
            "oLanguage": {
                "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ per page",
                "oPaginate": {
                    "sPrevious": "Prev",
                    "sNext": "Next"
                }
            },
            "aoColumnDefs": [{
                    'bSortable': false,
                    'aTargets': [0]
                }
            ]
        });
```

Now its displaying only first 10 records initailly .When i select ALL under dropdown its displaying all records .

```
        How can i make display all records at once without any pagination initially??
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing `"iDisplayLength": 5` to `"iDisplayLength": -1`

Comment: then please create a fiddle replicating your problem

Comment: @vladkras: as per google and datatable documentation this should solve the issue thats y posted as answer.

Comment: @CerlinBoss  I was refering to a wrong file (.js file) , now its working . Thank you very much